# ターミナルを起動すると　-bash: [: missing `]' とのメッセージが表示されます。

Tags: macos, bash

ターミナルを起動すると　-bash: [: missing `]' とのメッセージが表示されました。

こちらのサイトを参考にターミナルからSublimeText2を開けるよう設定しました。
http://offsidenow.phpapps.jp/archives/1669

その際、 .bash_profileを編集した際に不手際があったのか
その後ターミナルを立ち上げると

Last login: Sun Jun 21 23:35:02 on ttys000
-bash: [: missing `]'

というメッセージが表示されます。
原因がわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示頂けると幸いです。

Comment: `.bash_profile`の内容を差し支えない範囲で乗せていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

回答は書かれているので、補足として、

```
[ 1 -eq 1]
```

これはエラーになります。1 と ] の間に空白がないためです。
] は単独の引数として書くようにしましょう。

Comment: 有難う御座います。
勉強になりました。

Answer (score 2):

シェルの `test` コマンドには 見た目のために、"`[`" という別名があります。  
`test` が "`[`" という名前で呼ばれた時は、引数の最後に "`]`" を指定しなければいけない事になっています(見た目のためです)。

```
[ 1 -eq 1 ]
```

は

```
test 1 -eq 1
```

と同じ意味ですが、下記のように "`]`"を省略すると表題のエラーになります。

```
[ 1 -eq 1
# エラーになります -> bash: [: missing `]'
```

.bash_profile の編集でエラーが発生したのであれば、"`[`" に対応する "`]`" を消してしまったか、"`[`" を入れるべきで無い所に入れてしまったのでしょう。

Comment: 有難う御座います。
無事解決することが出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

直接の回答ではないのですが、ターミナル上で、

```
$ bash -l -x
```

を実行するとエラーが発生する場所が特定できるかと思います。ご参考までにどうぞ。